# propertyListWithData: curly braces causing error in "old style" plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, in-app-purchase, curly-braces

So I recently added some client-side IAP receipt validation, using Apple's widely-used [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/).

The sample is mostly about sending receipt data to Apple's server, essentially asking if it's a real receipt or not.  But it also includes some simple, locally-performed validation.  Part of that is getting the transaction's "purchase-info", a 64-bit encoded property list, describing the purchase.

That property list looks like this:

```
{
    "original-purchase-date-pst" = "2013-10-25 10:04:44 America/Los_Angeles";
    "unique-identifier" = "15546137c0c5c74672ce8b71223ad173fc2b2ac2";
    "original-transaction-id" = "1000000055641224";
    "bvrs" = "1.7";
    "transaction-id" = "100000008886513";
    "quantity" = "1";
    "original-purchase-date-ms" = "1382720684000";
    "unique-vendor-identifier" = "73F61531-4415-451B-A144-65165012BC51";
    "product-id" = "com.fakeco.FakeGame.GoldCookieBundle_1";
    "item-id" = "555555555";
    "bid" = "com.fakeco.FakeGame";
    "purchase-date-ms" = "1382720684000";
    "purchase-date" = "2013-10-25 17:04:44 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase-date-pst" = "2013-10-25 10:04:44 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original-purchase-date" = "2013-10-25 17:04:44 Etc/GMT";
}
```

Apple's code uses NSPropertyListSerialization's propertyListWithData: method to create a dictionary from this plist.  But this function returns an error for me:

```
kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError
Unexpected character { at line 1
```

So, after poking around Apple's docs a bit, I've learned that this ASCII key-value list is the ["old style"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html) representation of plists.

Depending on the format, the plist can represent an NSString, an NSArray, NSData, or and NSDictionary.  And the NSDicitonary, it says, "is enclosed in curly braces".  But the error I got complained that my opening curly brace was "unexpected".

So, as a test, I added some code to remove the braces before calling the propertyListWithData: method.

```
decodedPurchaseInfo = [decodedPurchaseInfo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
decodedPurchaseInfo = [decodedPurchaseInfo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
```

Then it worked!  The propertyListWithData: method properly returned an NSDictionary with the expected key-value pairs.

Does anyone have some insight that might help me out?  I find it hard to believe that I'm the only one running into this... I mean, others must use this sample code, right?

But what I definitely **don't** want to do is remove the braces and call it "fixed".
*"If you don't know why it's fixed, it's not fixed."*

Comment: Which string is it exactly that you have shown?

Comment: I've shown the value of "decodedPurchaseInfo", pulled from the transaction by the isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid: method in Apple's [VerificationController.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/VerificationController.zip) sample file.  
Regardless of where it came from, it looks like a validly-formatted "old style" plist.

Comment: Yes, it does. I have read your plist into an `NSData` object, and `propertyListWithData` worked just fine with it.

Comment: Very interesting, Martin.  What string encoding did you use?

Comment: I have just copied your plist into a file, and read that into a NSData object using dataWithContentsOfFile. The file was created as UTF-8, but that should not matter because it contains only ASCII characters. - Perhaps you can show the exact NSLog statements used, so that your output can be related to the VerificationController.m code.

Comment: You're right.  Something else is different about the string.  Because when I copy the contents to a hard-coded constant NSString, it actually works fine.  It's totally bizarre--I'm looking at two strings that seem to have identical content, and one works, and the other doesn't.  Digging further...

Comment: In my case, for some reason propertyListWithData: was returning an NSString instead of a dictionary.  There was no error.  Taking that string, removing the brackets, and calling propertyListWithData: a second time converted it to a dictionary.  (I was getting my plist from the Keychain, btw, not using IAP.)